# Restarting GStreamer Pipeline in Python on EOS

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gstreamer, python-gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I am working on a Python script running on RPi3, and using gstreamer to connect to RTSP feed of my IP Camera, and serve decoded H264 frames to my Python script.

Here is the gstreamear pipeline used to get frames from camera:

```
rtspsrc location=rtsp://ip:port/path ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! appsink name=sink
```

**Problem:** Since the camera is on a slow/unreliable internet connection, I get dropped frames every now and then, which causes an EOS signal to be generated. The internet connection bandwidth can be a problem sometimes causing a hick up with the stream.

**Goal**: On EOS signal, I would like to restart the pipeline so gstreamer can keep serving frames to my program.

**What I have tried:** I have a callback function attached to the bus that listens for messages by using

```
bus.connect("message", on_message)
```

Inside the "on_message" function, I am able to successfully determine if the message is an EOS signal. If I detect an EOS signal, I try to restart the pipeline by doing:

```
pipline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
pipline.set_state(Gst.State.PAUSED)
pipline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
```

Unfortunately this does not work. Once my scipt attemps to restart the pipeline using the snippet above, I get the following errors appearing on the bus. And I know the camera is online so that's not the problem.

```
('ERROR!!!:', 'source', '!:!', 'Could not read from resource.')
('Debug info:', 'gstrtspsrc.c(5583): gst_rtspsrc_send (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:source:\nGot error response: 400 (Bad Request).')
('ERROR!!!:', 'source', '!:!', 'Could not write to resource.')
('Debug info:', 'gstrtspsrc.c(6933): gst_rtspsrc_close (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:source:\nCould not send message. (Generic error)')
('ERROR!!!:', 'udpsrc2', '!:!', 'Internal data stream error.')
('Debug info:', 'gstbasesrc.c(2951): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:source/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc2:\nstreaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)')
```

In case the problem was with rtspsrc, I also tried using a short local video using filesrc, and using the EOS signal generated when gstreamer reaches end of the video file to test whether I am able to restart the pipeline. Here is an example pipeline I used to play local video:

```
filesrc location=file.mp4 ! qtdemux ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! appsink name=sink
```

If it is successful, it should start going through the video again, but no luck... Instead I am getting the following error, which makes me think that filesrc somehow needs to be reset. Same with the rtsp example, where there is an error being generated by rtspsrc

```
('ERROR!!!:', 'qtdemux0', '!:!', 'Internal data stream error.')
('Debug info:', 'qtdemux.c(5847): gst_qtdemux_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQTDemux:qtdemux0:\nstreaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)')
```

Can anybody shed any light on this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Are you creating your pipeline with gst_parse_launch or similar?

Answer (score 2):

If using `gst_parse_launch()` you can use `:` instead of `!` to make the 'pad-added' handling happen automatically.

```
fx: "videotestsrc ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! tsdemux : avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! ximagesink"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this (-1) error on pipelines where blocks have dynamically created source pads e.g. the rtpsrc, rtpbin, decodebin blocks are just three of the blocks that do this.

What I found was that you always need a "pad-added" handler.  Even in a 'scripted' pipeline.
You have to have program code installing pad-added handlers on your pipeline - in my pipelines I assigned names onto instances of blocks ( rtpbin name="rtpbin ) so you could locate them by known name.

This is because the general gstreamer launch using gst-launch-1.0 for example constructs the pipeline once correctly, but does not allow for dynamic source pads. All it does is exit if a new pad is created for a connection which already existed.

Despite the documentation which seems to imply that going to NULL state and back to PLAYING will reconnect the pipeline this is not true for these dynamically created pads which appear in documentation like "src_%u_%u_%u" where the second and third arguments to the format string are generated from inside the block concerned, and cannot be predicted by the user (the first %u is just the zero-based instance number ) .

In the normal gstreamer examples, all they tend to show is for a pad-added handler to create a link between a source and a sink pad if the sink pad is not connected.

In fact in the case of the pad-added handler call in one of these dynamically created pads, the source pad has changed identity and vanished, but the sink pad is still in 'connected' state.

What I found worked was to explicitly disconnect the sink pad .. something like this

```
// ... snip from pad_added_handler 

// If the pad believes it is linked, correctly or not, disconnect it 
if(gst_pad_is_linked(sinkPad))
{
   GstPad * peer = gst_pad_get_peer(sinkPad);
   if(peer) // unlink it if it has a peer
   { 
      gst_pad_unlink(peer,sinkPad);
      g_object_unref(peer); 
   }
}
// and link new or re-link existing pad
gst_pad_link( newPad, sinkPad); 
// ..
```

In my case, pipelines are constructed by calling gst_parse_bin_from_description() but the pad_added handlers are added by calling code with some additional metadata to allow locating the source instance by name, filter the new pad name and connect it to the sink instance.

Comment: This was the exact problem I had and the exact solution. I had `rtspsrc ! parsebin ! decodebin ! ...` and was restarting the pipeline on network errors, but when restarting, I always got `not-linked (-1)` error. Adding a pad added handler and disconnecting / reconnecting with sink pad of the next element fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

pipline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)

it does not mean that the pipeline has reached this state immediately. To be sure you can call pipeline.get_state(). Also I suggest to handle the return values for set_state(). Finally to get back to playing, there is no need to go to PAUSED first (unless you want to do something between PUASED and PLAYING).

Comment: So I added in some debug code to print pipeline status on the command line during certain points. When EOS is issued, the pipeline is still in `PLAYING` state. I am then able to put it into `READY` state, and then into `NULL` state. To bring the pipeline back up, I put the pipeline back into `READY` (confirm that it is ready by using `get_state()` ). But when I attempt to put it back into either `PLAYING` or `PAUSED`, I get the same error as before: `qtdemux.c(5847): gst_qtdemux_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQTDemux:qtdemux0:\nstreaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)`

Comment: When I use my RTSP source instead of local video playback, I get a very similar error, except this time from `rtspsrc` rather than `qtdemux`.
`'gstbasesrc.c(2951): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:source/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc2:\nstreaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)'`

Comment: Hmm, the not linked from qtdemux tells that it does not go through the same initialization when being reused as it would when it was new. That could be a bug. If you re-create the pipeline on EOS and it works, this would confirm it. Can you file a bug for gstreamer and add your python sample.

Comment: Yes sir, recreating the pipeline by overwriting the pipeline variable does get gstreamer going again. I tried unlinking elements one by one, and relinking them, but qtdemux does not want to link to the decoder. I even removed qtdemux from the pipeline, recreated a new qtdemux element, and linked it in there, but no dice. Do you have instructions for creating a bug, haven't done this before. Thanks!

Comment: Did you get it to work? I'm also trying to set the pipeline state to null and then playing when an EOS message is received on the gstreamer bus